# Rails: How to refresh table search results with Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am attempting to do a search of a MongoDB collection using a form. What I would like to do is update my results dynamically with Ajax versus having to refresh the page after each search form submit. How can I go about this in Rails?

scenarios_controller:

```
class ScenariosController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_scenario, only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :all_scenarios, only: [:index, :create, :update]
respond_to :html, :js

def index
  @scenarios = if params[:submitter].blank? && params[:application].blank? && params[:pillar].blank? && params[:test_type].blank? && params[:begin_date].blank? && params[:end_date].blank? && params[:search_text].blank?
               Scenario.all.order_by(created_at: :desc)
             else
               Scenario.search_text(params)
             end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
...
<div id="search_form_class">
  <%= render 'search_form', remote: true %>
</div>

<div id="results_class">
  <%= render 'results', remote: true %>
</div>
...
```

_search_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag(scenarios_path, remote: true, method: 'get', id: 'search-form', role: 'form') do %>
<%= select_tag :submitter, include_blank: true, class: "form-control" %>
<%= select_tag :application, include_blank: true, class: "form-control" %>
...
<% end %>
```

_search_form.js.erb:

```
$('#search-form').html("<%= j (render 'search_form', scenario: @scenario) %>")
```

_results.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="max-height: 800px; overflow:scroll;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Export?</th>
    <th>Submitter</th>
    <th>Scenario Name</th>
    <th>Scenario Body</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Modified</th>
    <th>Test Type</th>
    <th>Application</th>
    <th>Pillar</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    <th colspan="8"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @scenarios.each do |scenario| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><%= check_box_tag('compare') %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.submitter %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.scenario_name %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.scenario_body %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.created_at %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.updated_at %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.test_type %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.application %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.pillar %></td>
      <td><%= render 'options', scenario: scenario %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some important steps for achieving what you need. Below are the necessary steps that are required for your *AJAX* to work in *Rails* way.

**Step #1:**

Trigger an *AJAX* with `remote: true`. You already doing this.

**Step #2:**

By defining `remote: true` the request will be sent as `JS` to the controller action. You will need to write what need to done for the `JS` request.

```
def index
  if params[:submitter].blank? && params[:application].blank? && params[:pillar].blank? && params[:test_type].blank? && params[:begin_date].blank? && params[:end_date].blank? && params[:search_text].blank?
    @scenarios = Scenario.all.order_by(created_at: :desc)
   else
    @scenarios = Scenario.search_text(params)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**Step #3:**

Create `index.js.erb` under `/views/scenarios` with the below code

```
$('#results_class').html("<%= j (render 'results', scenarios: @scenarios) %>")
```

You need to change `@scenarios` to `scenarios` in `_results.html.erb`

**Step #4:**

Change this

```
<%= render 'results', remote: true %>
```

to this

```
<%= render 'results', scenarios: @scenarios %>
```

to avoid a potential error.

Also remove `remote: true` here `<%= render 'search_form', remote: true %>`. It is weird and probably a wrong syntax.

Comment: I implemented your changes and now have a working search function with Ajax on Rails. Thank you @Pavan!!